# Nodejs Do I need to use Passport

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, web, passport.js

Alright, so I'm currently coding a Web Application with Node.js, and I'm a bit stuck on how I should handle user logins/authentication.

Lots of tutorials seem to recommend using Passport for your authentication, but from all the documentation I've read, it seems to take a bit of setting up and it complicates the simple login I was expecting.

Whether or not I use Passport, I still plan on hashing my user passwords that are stored in the Mongo database.

So the question is, do I need to use Passport for security reasons, or can I just code an authentication system my self?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's really up to you, if you don't need Facebook, Google, or Twitter logins or are fine coding your own, I would just build it from scratch.

I built an application that didn't need all the bells and whistles that Passport came with, but needed it's own security built in, and found it much easier to just make my own.  It's so easy to include your security as middleware in node!

Comment: Thanks, I'll go code my own Authentication system :)

Comment: no problem!  Just in case you haven't built middleware in node yet, make sure you pass your middleware function next and then call it!  like `function(req, res, next)`  and then if your security resolves call `next()` just make sure you don't call it on errors.  If you have done it, I will just leave this here for someone else to read if it's their first time.

Comment: Question: What would the middleware actually do that you speak of building yourself? Does it do something other than validate input and compute/compare hash?

Comment: Nope that is all you really need to do, I used a cache/database lookup to verify the person.  But that should be all you'll need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends your use.Generally set a password is necessary, and use passport is not complicated in Nodejs .Of course ,if your application is used in internal，password can be ignored.But I think security is provided.